# HttpContext.Current is NULL in NServiceBus MessageMutator

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have a problem with HttpContext.Current being NULL using NServiceBus decoupling front-end (MVC) and back-end (Azure WorkerRole).
I’m using IMutateTransportMessages to intercept outgoing and incoming TransportMessages. I have some data in the Session (MVC front-end) and need to automatically append it to the outgoing TransportMessages using Mutators. Analogous I need to inject some data from incoming TransportMessages into the Session.

For better understanding let’s take a look at my simplified scenario:

Fron-end:

1. I have data *D1* in the Session
2. I send CommandX to NServiceBus >> MutateOutgoing [take data *D1* form the Session and insert it the TransportMerssage header *H1*] >> message is sent to the bus

Back-end:
 3. I receive CommandX with header *H1* containing data *D1*
 4. I do some stuff
 5. I add data *D2* into the message header *H2* and return CommanX to NServiceBus

Front-end:
 6. I get CommandX “response” in NServiceBus >> MutateIncomming [I have data *D2* in the header *H2* from the back-end and I wish to inject this data into the Session so I can use it in MVC front-end but I can’t, since the HttpContext.Current is **null**]

Any ideas, why I can access the Session from MutateOutgoing and not from MutateIncomming? Any workarounds?

Thank you!
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MutateIncoming will be called on an NServiceBus worker thread and not on an ASP.NET worker thread - hence no HTTP context.

Think of it - what would you expect the HTTP context to be when you're handling an NServiceBus message?

If you need something from the user's session, you'd probably need to pass some kind of session ID or correlation ID around, allowing you leave the data in the right place when the reply message gets handled.

Comment: Yep, you are right, thank you. The answer on NServiceBus community forum: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/19451